# Fusion of GNSS position data and prefused 9-dof AHRS data

Tags: quadcopter, kalman-filter, imu, gps, sensor-fusion

Bosch, FreeScale, InvenSense, ST and maybe others are releasing 9-dof AHRS platforms containing their own fusion software and outputting **filtered/sane/fused** data (attitude as quaternion and linear acceleration).

I would like to use these for the quality of their respective company fusion algorithm. And would like to merge GNSS position and velocity data to it.

I have found multiple examples of heavy (> 20) states Kalman filters merging **raw** 9-dof IMU data and GNSS position/velocity.

But I have a hard time finding a **computationally lighter** version of GPS+AHRS fusion as these new 9-dof AHRS already fuse IMU raw data themselves and this process should'nt be done twice.

Would you maybe have pointers on the algorithm(s) or type of filter to use ? Thank you.

Comment: How much computationally lighter is your requirement? what platform do you wish to use? Which examples have you already referred?

Comment: Lighter as in avoiding recomputing what the other controller has already fused (acc/gyro/mag). Platform is Cortex-M4 with FPU. The microcontroller isn't saturated but the less processing time, the less power consummed. Filter can be derived of Kalman too. Closest I found is "pose_ekf StatePosVelOriAcc" predicting with acceleration and gyro and then correcting with GPS position, GPS velocity and attitude quaternion. Others are PX4 previous attitude_position_EKF or Paul Riseborough InertialNav but they fuse accel, gyro and mag with > 15 states filters. Thank you !

Comment: Another ideal solution would be to find an equivalent of the aforementioned companies solutions allowing the input of position and velocity data to their fusion algorithm. I went through these 4 companies datasheets and they don't. Maybe another does ?

Comment: Koen -- I understand its been a while since you posted this question, but this post has references to some off-the-shelf modules that I believe are doing what you are interested in --- http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/7815/are-there-off-the-shelf-solutions-for-gpsins-accelerometer-gyro-magneto-senso. Perhaps using these modules can be an option. If you have solved your problem, I would like to know how (I would benefit from using the similar approach). Thank you